# subclasses of abstract class object is null when using autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, autowired

I have these classes. when I debug I see that the spring creates the service object in constructor and called the constructors in both classes but when I want to use the fields, they are null. What's the problem?! (type1Processor, type2Processor and type3Processor are null)

```
import com.vali.ReactiveSocketServer.service.ReceivedDataService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public abstract class Processor {

public ReceivedDataService receivedDataService;

public Processor(ReceivedDataService receivedDataService) {
    this.receivedDataService = receivedDataService;
}

public abstract void readStream(String stream);
}
```

and this is its subclass

```
import com.vali.ReactiveSocketServer.model.ReceivedData;
import com.vali.ReactiveSocketServer.service.ReceivedDataService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Type1Processor extends Processor {


@Autowired
public Type1Processor(ReceivedDataService receivedDataService) {
    super(receivedDataService);
}

@Override
public void readStream(String stream) {
    System.out.println("readStream "+ getClass().getSimpleName() + "-" + stream);
    receivedDataService.add(new ReceivedData(stream.getBytes()));
}
}
```

and this is its usage:

```
import com.vali.ReactiveSocketServer.processor.Processor;
import com.vali.ReactiveSocketServer.processor.Type1Processor;
import com.vali.ReactiveSocketServer.processor.Type2Processor;
import com.vali.ReactiveSocketServer.processor.Type3Processor;
import com.vali.ReactiveSocketServer.receivers.AppServer;
import com.vali.ReactiveSocketServer.socket.ClientHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ReactiveSocketServerApplication {

private AppServer appServer;

@Autowired
Type1Processor type1Processor;

@Autowired
Type2Processor type2Processor;

@Autowired
Type3Processor type3Processor;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ReactiveSocketServerApplication.class, args);

    ReactiveSocketServerApplication reactiveSocketServerApplication = new ReactiveSocketServerApplication();
    reactiveSocketServerApplication.Start();
}


public void Start(){

    appServer = AppServer.getInstance();

    Map<Integer, Processor> processorMap = new HashMap<>();

    processorMap.put(7001, type1Processor);
    processorMap.put(7002, type2Processor);
    processorMap.put(7003, type3Processor);

    appServer.initialize(processorMap);

    new ClientHandler(7001, 1000);
    new ClientHandler(7002, 5000);
}
}
```

Comment: when I want to put them in Map they are null, in this line `processorMap.put(7001, type1Processor);`

Comment: Look there, similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399924/spring-boot-autowired-in-main-class-is-getting-null

Comment: can you pls share package structure of the classes above?

Comment: @mario45211 thank you. I just add `@PostConstruct` to my start method and it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are instantiating `ReactiveSocketServerApplication` yourself.

So spring can't inject the `@Autowired` annotated beans, because the instance was created outside of it's life cycle.

Remove this completly:

```
ReactiveSocketServerApplication reactiveSocketServerApplication = new ReactiveSocketServerApplication();
reactiveSocketServerApplication.Start();
```

And annotate your `Start()` with `@PostConstruct`:

```
@PostConstruct
public void Start() { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing `@Component` in the abstract class `ReceivedDataService`.

This mean when you create the subclases using :

```
@Autowired
public Type1Processor(ReceivedDataService receivedDataService) {
   super(receivedDataService);
}
```

Can't inject ReceivedDataService and get the default value(`null`)

Comment: I tried that (with or without @Component) but it's not working

Comment: Did you try debugg at constructor of any child class?

Comment: yes. I found it with help of mario. I should use `@PostConstruct` for my start method

Comment: Abstract classes don't need to be annotated as a `Component` as Spring can't instantiate them