# Autowiring in spring is null in src package

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, cucumber

For test framework were used next stack of technologies:
Java, Maven, Selenium, Junit, Cucumber, Spring Boot, YAML

---

Were used spring boot starter and test

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

---

Spring boot app

```
package io.tpd.springbootcucumber;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootCucumberApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootCucumberApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

Cucumber step definitions class - in test package

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootCucumberApplication.class)
public class StepDefinitions {

    @Autowired
    private Config config;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    private ScenarioContext scenarioContext;
```

in src/test/java directory i can autowired in every class, but in scr/main/java if i autowired my component it's null

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399924/spring-boot-autowired-in-main-class-is-getting-null