# Spring boot @Autowired field is null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have `abcController` field which is null in my **Abc.class**:

```
@Service(id = "ABC", name = "service-abc") // THIS IS NOT SPRING ANNOTATION it marks class as Service Singleton, loads custom annotations like @AfterInitialization
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.package*")
@ComponentScan("healthchecker")
public class Abc {
    
    @Autowired
    AbcController abcController;

    @AfterInitialization
    public void afterInit() throws GwConfigurationException {

        // initialize Spring Boot
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Dmsgw.class);

        // run with command line arguments
        CmdLineArguments cmdLineArguments = new CmdLineArguments();
        String[] args = cmdLineArguments.getArgStrings();
        
        if (args == null) {
            args = new String[0];
        }
        
        application.run(args);
 
        abcController.doSomething(); // abcController is null
    }
}
```

This is my **AbcController.class**:

```
@Service
public class AbcController {

    ...// some fields

    ...// some methods
}
```

I tried so far to annotate `abcController` with `@Service` or `@Component` or `@Controller` but it's the same.

This is `MyServiceConfiguration.class`:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AbcController defaultAbcController() {
        return new AbcController();
    }
}
```

I checked and the Bean was loaded.

Comment: I think you cannot add autowired beans to a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, because this just serves a an entrypoint.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was wrong, perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399924/spring-boot-autowired-in-main-class-is-getting-null) can help you

Comment: In which package AbcController is located? And your Abc class?

Comment: @nkrivenko com.package.abc.controller

Comment: @nkrivenko abc.class is located on com.package

Comment: If all your components are in subpackage of com.package then you don't need @ComponentScan annotations

Comment: Ofcourse it is `null`. That method is invoked by something else as Spring BOot. So eventually yu will endup with 2 instances of your `Abc` class. 1 that is injected, another that isn't.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you know how to handle this? AbcController must be injected.

Comment: You are using another framework which should integrate with Spring. If that doesn't integrate it won't work without going through loops.